# Get continent name from country name in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column representing country names. My goal is to add one more column which gives the continent information. Please check the following use case:

```
my.df <- data.frame(country = c("Afghanistan","Algeria"))
```

Is there a package that I can use to append a column of data containing the continent names without having the original data?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [`countrycode`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/countrycode/) package for this task.

```
library(countrycode)
df <- data.frame(country = c("Afghanistan",
                             "Algeria",
                             "USA",
                             "France",
                             "New Zealand",
                             "Fantasyland"))

df$continent <- countrycode(sourcevar = df[, "country"],
                            origin = "country.name",
                            destination = "continent")
#warning
#In countrycode(sourcevar = df[, "country"], origin = "country.name",  :
#  Some values were not matched unambiguously: Fantasyland
```

Result

```
df
#      country continent
#1 Afghanistan      Asia
#2     Algeria    Africa
#3         USA  Americas
#4      France    Europe
#5 New Zealand   Oceania
#6 Fantasyland      <NA>
```

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on Markus' answer, `countrycode` draws on `codelist`s 'continent' declaration.

```
?codelist
```

Definition of `continent`:

> continent: Continent as defined in the World Bank Development Indicators

The question asked for continents but sometimes continents don't provide enough groups for you to delineate the data. For example, `continents` groups North and South America into `Americas`.

What you might want is `region`:

> region: Regions as defined in the World Bank Development Indicators

It is unclear how the World Bank groups regions but the below code shows how this destination is more granular.

```
library(countrycode)

egnations <- c("Afghanistan","Algeria","USA","France","New Zealand","Fantasyland")

countrycode(sourcevar = egnations, origin = "country.name",destination = "region")
```

Output:

```
[1] "Southern Asia"            
[2] "Northern Africa"          
[3] "Northern America"         
[4] "Western Europe"           
[5] "Australia and New Zealand"
[6] NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
my.df <- data.frame(country = c("Afghanistan","Algeria"),
                    continent= as.factor(c("Asia","Africa")))
merge(my.df, raster::ccodes()[,c("NAME", "CONTINENT")], by.x="country", by.y="NAME", all.x=T)
#       country continent CONTINENT
# 1 Afghanistan      Asia      Asia
# 2     Algeria    Africa    Africa
```

Some `country` values might need an adjustment; I dunno since you did not provide all values.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without specifying the values for countries, inc ase we have more than a 100 values?