# creating a new column based on a set of strings conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have this column with a lot of countries.

`countries <- c(Germany, France, Japan, China, Angola, Nigeria)`

I want to create a new column called continent, agreggating these places. For example, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if (countries == "Germany" | "France" {
   countries$continents <- "Europe"
 } else if (countries == "Japan"  |"China") {
   countries$continents <- "Asia"
 } else if (countries == "Angola"  |"Nigeria") {
   countries$continents <- "África"
```

But R keep saying me i'm not allowed to compare strings.
Maybe dplyr might have a clever solution, but any solution is welcomed. How I do this?

Comment: This post might be helpful: [Get continent name from country name in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510141/get-continent-name-from-country-name-in-r)

Comment: What you would need to use is `%in%`, e.g. `countries %in% c("Germany", "France")`. You compare a logical vector (`countries == "Germany"`) to a string `"France"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @markus pointed out use %in%

You could try this using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(countries = c("Germany", "France", "Japan", "China", "Angola", "Nigeria"))



df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(continent = case_when(countries %in% c("Germany", "France") ~ "Europe",
                               countries %in% c("Japan", "China") ~ "Asia",
                               countries %in% c("Angola", "Nigeria") ~ "Africa"))
```

But it might be neater to use the `countrycode` package, again as noted by @markus

```
library(countrycode)

df_continents <- 
  codelist %>% 
  select(country.name.en, continent)

df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  left_join(df_continents, by = c("countries" = "country.name.en"))

df2

#>   countries continent
#> 1   Germany    Europe
#> 2    France    Europe
#> 3     Japan      Asia
#> 4     China      Asia
#> 5    Angola    Africa
#> 6   Nigeria    Africa
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>